# Python new column based on NaN in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, nan, nonetype

I'm quite new to Python and this is my first ever question so please be gentle with me!

I have tried out answers to other similar questions but am still quite stuck.

I am using Pandas and I have a dataframe which is a merge from multiple different SQL tables and looks something like this:

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3   Col_4
1       NaN     NaN     NaN
2       Y       NaN     NaN
3       Z       C       S
4       NaN     B       W
```

I don't care about the values in Col_2 Col_3 and Col_4 (note these can be strings or integers or objects depending on the column)

I just care that at least one of these columns is populated so ideally would like a fifth column like:

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3   Col_4   Col_5
1       NaN     NaN     NaN     0
2       Y       NaN     NaN     1
3       Z       C       S       1
4       NaN     B       W       1
```

Then I want to drop the columns Col_2 to Col_4.

My initial thought was something like the function below, but this is reducing my dataframe from 50000 rows to 50. I don't want to delete any rows.

```
def function(row):
   if (isnull.row['col_2'] and isnull.row['col_3'] and isnull.row['col_3'] is None):
      return '0'
   else:
      return '1'

df['col_5'] = df.apply(lambda row: function (row),axis=1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I gather you are using a pandas DataFrame.  I've added the `pandas` tag to your question.  In general, you need to mention if you're using a third-party library (like pandas) that is not part of the Python standard library.

Comment: Thanks I'll also update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) and pass param `axis=1` which tests row-wise this will produce a boolean array which when converted to int will convert all `True` values to `1` and `False` values to `0`, this will be much faster than calling `apply` which is going to iterate row-wise and will be very slow:

```
In [30]:

df['Col_5'] = any(df[df.columns[1:]].notnull(), axis=1).astype(int)
df
Out[30]:
   Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4  Col_5
0      1   NaN   NaN   NaN      0
1      2     Y   NaN   NaN      1
2      3     Z     C     S      1
3      4   NaN     B     W      1

In [31]:

df = df[['Col_1', 'Col_5']]
df
Out[31]:
   Col_1  Col_5
0      1      0
1      2      1
2      3      1
3      4      1
```

Here is the output from `any`:

```
In [34]:

any(df[df.columns[1:]].notnull(), axis=1)
Out[34]:
array([False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

**Timings**

```
In [35]:

%timeit df[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: all(x.isnull()) , axis=1).astype(int)
%timeit any(df[df.columns[1:]].notnull(), axis=1).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.46 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop
```

So on your test data for a df this size my method is over 2x faster than the other answer

**Update**

As you are running pandas version `0.12.0` then you need to call the top level [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html#pandas.isnull) version as that method is not available at df level:

```
any(pd.notnull(df[df.columns[1:]]), axis=1).astype(int)
```

I suggest you upgrade as you'll get lots more features and bug fixes.

Comment: I believe the OP wants an `OR` operation on the row,column pairs where your implementation is an `AND` operation. OP just wants to make `col5` true if at least 1 non-NaN value exists in columns 2-4.

Comment: @aus_lacy actually I just need to invert the operation, rather than OR it

Comment: I tried using `any()` and `~` with your implementation for kicks and grins and was unable to get it to work so I will be interested to see your inversion.

Comment: @aus_lacy I've updated it but I need to tidy up a bit

Comment: Ah `notnull()`. Missed that one.

Comment: @EdChum I tried the suggestion but when I run the any I get an attribute error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
----> 1 any(BigFive[BigFive.columns[6:]].notnull(), axis=1)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'notnull'

Comment: @coghmeister I think you must be running an old version of pandas try: `any(~df[df.columns[1:]].isnull(), axis=1).astype(int)` also could you post your pandas version and are you able to upgrade?

Comment: I'm using version 0.12.0 and I guess I can't upgrade because it is the version we have at work. Thanks for the suggestion, i get an attribute error for isnull as well

Comment: does `any(pd.notnull(df[df.columns[1:]]), axis=1).astype(int)` work?

Comment: Yes it did! I had in the meantime tried: 

df['newcolumn'] = any(~pandas.isnull(df[df.columns[6:]]), axis=1).astype(int)

and this syntax seems to work too for the older version. Thanks @EdChum

Answer (score 0):

using a function:

```
df['col_5'] =df.apply(lambda x: all(x.isnull()) , axis=1)
```

for my money is a bit easier to read. Not sure which is quicker.