# Creating column to keep track of missing values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I am adding a mock dataframe to exemplify my problem.

I have a large dataframe in which some columns are missing values.
I would like to create some extra boolean columns in which 1 corresponds to a non missing value in the row and 0 corresponds to a missing value.

```
names = ['Banana, Andrew Something (Maria Banana)', np.nan, 'Willis, Mr. Bruce (Demi Moore)', 'Crews, Master Terry', np.nan]

room = [100, 330, 212, 111, 222]

hotel_loon = {'Name' : pd.Series(names), 'Room' : pd.Series(room)}

hotel_loon_df = pd.DataFrame(hotel_loon)
```

In another question I found on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244153/python-new-column-based-on-nan-in-other-columns) they were super thorough and clear on how to proceed to keep track of all the columns that have missing values but not for specific ones.
I tried a few variations of that code (namely using where) but I was not successful with creating what I wanted which would be something like this:

```
                                       Name Room Name_present Room_present
0   Banana, Andrew Something (Maria Banana) 100             1            1 
1                                      NaN  330             0            1
2          Willis, Mr. Bruce (Demi Moore)   212             1            1
3                    Crews, Master Terry    111             1            1
4                                    NaN    222             0            1
```

Thank you for your time, I am sure that in the end it is going to be trivial, but for some reason I got stuck.

Comment: Came across this method of handling nulls.
Just curious why do we need to go for keeping track of all the columns that have missing values? Are you using this 'Name_present' and 'Room_present' as features for model training?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.isnull()` for your case, and change the type from `bool` to `int`:

```py
hotel_loon_df['Name_present'] = (~hotel_loon_df['Name'].isnull()).astype(int)
hotel_loon_df['Room_present'] = (~hotel_loon_df['Room'].isnull()).astype(int)

Out[1]: 
                                      Name  Room  Name_present  Room_present
0  Banana, Andrew Something (Maria Banana)   100             1             1
1                                      NaN   330             0             1
2           Willis, Mr. Bruce (Demi Moore)   212             1             1
3                      Crews, Master Terry   111             1             1
4                                      NaN   222             0             1
```

The `~` means the opposite of, or something that is not.

Comment: This is a really great solution! I was very close to the right way but it seems like I was consistently forgetting the tilde, I appreciate your time and effort in unblocking a stranger. Is there any reading you would suggest to keep these concepts more present? Again, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome @bls. [learn python the hard way](https://web.itu.edu.tr/hulyayalcin/MAK230E_PythonProgramming/%5B2014%5D%5BShaw%5DLEARNPYTHONTHE%20HARDWAY.pdf) is a good source (no affiliation). However, nothing beats trial and error in real projects.

Comment: Spent the last hour going through it, thank you for pointing me the right way! I seems like a great resource.

Answer (score 4):

To save some typing, use `DataFrame.notnull`, add some suffixes, and join the result back.

```
pd.concat([df, df.notnull().astype(int).add_suffix('_present')], axis=1)

                                      Name  Room  Name_present  Room_present
0  Banana, Andrew Something (Maria Banana)   100             1             1
1                                      NaN   330             0             1
2           Willis, Mr. Bruce (Demi Moore)   212             1             1
3                      Crews, Master Terry   111             1             1
4                                      NaN   222             0             1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are tracking only for Nan fields, you can use isnull() function.

```
df['name_present'] =df['name'].isnull()
df['name_present'].replace(True,0, inplace=True) 
df['name_present'].replace(False,1, inplace=True) 
df['room_present'] =df['room'].isnull()
df['room_present'].replace(True,0, inplace=True)
df['room_present'].replace(False,1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a concise manner by using `DataFrame.isnull`:

```
hotel_loon_df[['Name_present', 'Room_present']] = (~hotel_loon_df.isnull()).astype(int)

                                      Name  Room  Name_present  Room_present
0  Banana, Andrew Something (Maria Banana)   100             1             1
1                                      NaN   330             0             1
2           Willis, Mr. Bruce (Demi Moore)   212             1             1
3                      Crews, Master Terry   111             1             1
4                                      NaN   222             0             1
```